# Cheap system to keep mice from drowning in a pool?

Tags: outdoor, pool, home-automation, security

Sometimes small mice end up jumping into my pool and drowning. I should install a cover, but in the meantime does anyone have an easier system? I have one of those off-ramps for small animals already, but maybe there is a better version. Also maybe there is some kind of motion detector or image analysis software to alert me?

Comment: You need to hire a little toad as a lifeguard.

Comment: There are hydra phone “splash” detectors for pools but I doubt they would detect something as small as a mouse. They were also fairly expensive but that was 25+ years ago. Might be worth checking into.

Comment: Place a drinking bowl for them.

Comment: Do you want to handle a rodent if a motion detector gave you an alert? How long can they swim before you get to them? How are they getting onto, subsequently into your pool? Is this above ground or at ground level? A ramp is something you probably want to remove not add. I agree with your initial thought, you should install a pool cover. The benefits of using a cover are generally worth it. It would also keep the pool clean from other things as well and may reduce the chemicals you need to use (assuming you do).

Comment: Thanks! I think they can swim for around an hour, not sure. The pool is at ground level and I'm not sure that's how they are getting in. They may be getting in using the ramp, but they also were getting in some other way before I got the ramp.

Comment: Attract a feral cat?

Comment: @bishop MIND BLOWN ^-^

Comment: probably need some more exit ramps.

Comment: I guess buy some cheap bubble wrap from a home store ... like 12-24" wide on a roll, and drop some bricks or rocks on it use as much as you can around the perimeter, basically this creates a whole lot of ramp for them. I wonder who will get more enjoyment from the pool, them or you? Getting a cover will be the best bet. Bubble wrap is cheap, it will break down over a season, but critters claws can use it to get out.